# Weird form error

Tags: c#, error-handling

I'm working on something in c# and I get an error when I try to execute this code

```
Code:
Form form3 = new Form3();
                    form3.Show;
```

Heres the error I get

```
Error: 
only assignment ,call ,increasement ,decreasement ,and new object expressions 
can be used as a statement
```

I usually dont get this error when I'm coding
& thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form3.Show` looks like the culprit.  It should be `form3.Show()`.  Without the parens it doesn't execute the method.

Answer (score 7):

Just a typo, man:

```
Form form3 = new Form();
```

You called `Form`, `Form3` when you called the constructor.

=)

EDIT:  You also weren't calling the `Show` and `close` functions properly:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  Form form3 = new Form(); 
  form3.Show(); 
  this.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: @Matthewj: You may have another syntax error nearby then.  Can you post the lines before and after these?

Comment: @Michael: LOL.  Ok, I have put a comma to reduce the confusion =)

Comment: private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form form3 = new Form();
            form3.Show;
            this.close;
        }

Comment: @Matthewj: Ok, I see the problem.  You were trying to use `show` and `close` as properties instead of methods.